# Sound in android programs doesn't work

Tags: java, android, audio

Good day I have been doing some coding in the for my android program and i tried playing a music with this code right here android the lowest build is 2.2 and highest is 4.2.2 also using eclipse to do this and the device emulator is nexus one

this in the globe

```
    MediaPlayer Sound;
```

and this is in the under the setContentView

```
    Sound = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.kalimba);
    Sound.start();
```

and this is the entire code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Splash extends Activity {
MediaPlayer Sound;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Sound = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.kalimba);
    Sound.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);                    
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoints = new              Intent("com.mysampleapp.simplybel.MainActivity");
                startActivity(openStartingPoints);
            }//this is the end for the finally
        }//this is the end for the run
    };//this is the end for the thread timer
    timer.start();

}//this is the end for the oncreate

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Sound.release();
    finish();
}


}
```

can anybody help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

It may be coming from your intent. What exactly are you trying to do with this intent?

The correct syntax for an explicit intent should be like in this [intent tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/). For example,
`Intent openStartingPoints=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);` and context must be outside the thread like `Context context;` as a global variable declaration and instantiate it with `context=this;` inside of onCreate() to set it to the context of the current activity.

As another suggestion, you should always name variable names in camel case so the first letter should be lowercase.

Let me know if this changes anything. Other than that I can't see any problems with the code provided.